# Can't increment date with ddmmyyyy format in bash

Tags: bash, date

Why does this:

```
date +%d%m%Y -d "01052018 + 1 day"
```

error w/

```
date: invalid date `02062018 + 1 day'
```

on CentOS 7.3 in CEST? I've tried a few variations

```
date +%d%m%Y -d "$date 12:00 + 1 day"
date +%d%m%Y -ud "$date UTC + 1 day"
```

to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: On my system I reproduce the error, even without the `+ 1 day`, but it disappear if I use separators, e.g. `date +%d%m%Y -d "01/05/2018 + 1 day"` . I suppose `01052018` is ambiguous.

Comment: isnt the point of `+%d%m%Y` that it's not ambiguous!

Comment: From `man date`: "FORMAT controls the output." I don't think it changes the way the input date is parsed

Comment: @mathematician:  Did the answer work out for you? Upvote/accept if it solved your problem

Answer (score 4):

GNU date does not support date format **ddmmyyyy** of type as you can see from [Pure numbers in date strings](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Pure-numbers-in-date-strings.html#Pure-numbers-in-date-strings), you need to change it of type **yyyymmdd** to make it work

```
date -d "20180501 + 1 day"
```

or with UTC as

```
date -ud "20180501 UTC + 1 day"
```

If your original string is from a variable and you need a work-around to make it compatible with the format above, do it using parameter expansion

```
rawdate="02062018"
compatDate="${rawdate:4}${rawdate:2:2}${rawdate:0:2}"
```

and use the variable `compatDate` in the `date` command

```
date -d "${compatDate} + 1 day"
```